# Want to call batch file with node script, get garbled time

Tags: node.js, bash

I want to create a cron job with a batch file which is using curl to login into a page saving the login token and then run a node script to do something. But when I call my batch file I get

```
    batch: garbled time
```

My script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # A simple script to automate something

    curl 'someurl' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: someurl' --data-binary '{"some login data"}' -i -O
    node doSomething.js
```

Comment: The `batch-file` tag is for `*.bat` files for the Windows, OS/2 and MS-DOS operating systems. You're using Bash. Are you sure you've got the right tag?

Comment: ah yeah you are right I use it for the first time. I think its #!/usr/bin/env bash

Comment: aaaaah its not 

        batch script

its 

        sh script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to submit your script as a crontab file, then it's in the wrong format. You need to specify time-related fields at the start of the line. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

The error message you got is typical of a bad time specification.

Comment: yeah thx, but it was a wrong command. I used "batch script" instead of "sh script"